# Баг linq, entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

В строке
`Buffer = unBuffer;
unBuffer.Clear();`

вместе с UnBuffer чиститься и сам Buffer почему то, вот полный код

```
public List<SubForum> GetAllTreeSubForums(SubForum subForum)
    {
        List<SubForum> allSubList = new List<SubForum>(); // Основной список

        bool isOver = false;
        var Buffer = GetChildSubForum(subForum); // В начале это 1 глубина
        var unBuffer = new List<SubForum>();

        while(isOver == false)
        {
            allSubList.AddRange(Buffer);

            foreach(var podBuffer in Buffer)
            {
                var a = GetChildSubForum(podBuffer);

                unBuffer.AddRange(a);
            }

            if (unBuffer.Count() == 0)
            {
                allSubList.AddRange(Buffer);
                isOver = true;
            }

            Buffer = unBuffer;
            unBuffer.Clear();
        }

        return allSubList;
    }
```

Comment: Просто не могу понять из-за чего это, даже нет мыслей из-за чего такое может быть, может Clear очищает Buffer так как думает что Buffer = unBuffer, или просто они не успевают поменяться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Buffer = unBuffer;
```

После этой строки обе переменные указывают на один и тот же объект (из-за `var` не знаю тип, но предполагаю, что `List<SubForum>`). Вы его очищаете, после этого обе переменные указывают на все тот же список, но уже пустой. Если вы хотели скопировать не ссылку, а сам список, вам следовало воспользоваться копирующим конструктором:

```
Buffer = List<SubForum>(unBuffer);
```

Comment: Buffer = new List<SubForum>(unBuffer) * Действительно, заработало, спасибо!

Comment: @JigglyDezar, для предотвращения подобных вопросов в будущем разберитесь, чем отличаются ссылочные типы от типов значений. Присваивание для них работает по-разному.